# TanstackQuery V5 pageParam does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, react-query, tanstackreact-query

i have this code. in v5 tanstack i get problem with. in v4 is not have this problem

const queryFn: QueryFunction<Awaited<ReturnType>> = ({pageParam}) =>
notificationControllerGetNotification({cursor: pageParam, ...params}, axiosOptions);

TS2339: Property 'pageParam' does not exist on type '{ queryKey: QueryKey; signal: AbortSignal; meta: Record<string, unknown> | undefined; }'.

i didn't find this error in documentation

`

```
export interface NotificationListEntity {
    createdAt: string;
    entityId?: string | null;
    entityType: NotificationEntityType;
    id: string;
    message: string;
    read: boolean;
    title: string;
    trigger: NotificationTrigger;
    type: NotificationType;
}

export const notificationControllerGetNotification = (
    params?: NotificationControllerGetNotificationParams,
    options?: AxiosRequestConfig,
): Promise<AxiosResponse<NotificationListEntity[]>> => {
    return axios.default.get(`/api/notifications`, {
        ...options,
        params: {...params, ...options?.params},
    });
};

export const getNotificationControllerGetNotificationInfiniteQueryOptions = <
    TData = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof notificationControllerGetNotification>>,
    TError = AxiosError<NotificationListEntity[]>,
>(
    params?: NotificationControllerGetNotificationParams,
    options?: {
        query?: UseInfiniteQueryOptions<
            Awaited<ReturnType<typeof notificationControllerGetNotification>>,
            TError,
            TData
        >;
        axios?: AxiosRequestConfig;
    },
) => {
    const {query: queryOptions, axios: axiosOptions} = options ?? {};

    const queryKey = queryOptions?.queryKey ?? getNotificationControllerGetNotificationQueryKey(params);

    const queryFn: QueryFunction<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof notificationControllerGetNotification>>> = ({pageParam}) =>
        notificationControllerGetNotification({cursor: pageParam, ...params}, axiosOptions);

    return {queryKey, queryFn, ...queryOptions} as UseInfiniteQueryOptions<
        Awaited<ReturnType<typeof notificationControllerGetNotification>>,
        TError,
        TData
    > & {queryKey: QueryKey};
};
```

i try write different options and also try write pageParam: TPageParam like documentation

Answer (score 0):

Since v5, the type `QueryFunction` has 3 generics:

```
export type QueryFunction<
  T = unknown,
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey,
  TPageParam = never,
> = (context: QueryFunctionContext<TQueryKey, TPageParam>) => T | Promise<T>
```

`TPageParam` is passed to `QueryFunctionContext`, where it will determine if `pageParam` is available at runtime or not:

```
export type QueryFunctionContext<
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey,
  TPageParam = never,
> = [TPageParam] extends [never]
  ? {
      queryKey: TQueryKey
      signal: AbortSignal
      meta: QueryMeta | undefined
    }
  : {
      queryKey: TQueryKey
      signal: AbortSignal
      pageParam: TPageParam
      direction: FetchDirection
      meta: QueryMeta | undefined
    }
```

since you pass one type parameter to `QueryFunction`, the other two default to their respective default values:

```
const queryFn: QueryFunction<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof notificationControllerGetNotification>>> = ({pageParam}) => ...
```

so you need to provide all 3 type parameters:

```
const queryFn: QueryFunction<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof notificationControllerGetNotification>>, QueryKey, number> = ({pageParam}) =>
```

`QueryKey` and `number` are just an example here, as I don't know how a valid `pageParam` will look for your case.

---

on a different note: I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but it looks unnecessarily complex. We also have an `infiniteQueryOptions` helper function to create type-safe options that you can then pass to `useInfiniteQuery`...